# Start Centos without cronjobs

Tags: cron, centos

I've a very big problem. How I can startup ma centos server without the cronjobs defined in the crontab -e?
I've to disable temporally this feature because I can't login anymore in the server because there is an infinite loop in the sh file that start at the login.
I've to disable all cronjobs at startup, but I can't login in the server

Thanks
Davide

Comment: Please say me because of down vote please so I can improver my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem:
I've insert the hard disk in another computer as external hard drive. After that I followed word par word the following link: http://pissedoffadmins.com/os/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member.html

Answer (score 0):

Once your server starts, try this command and make the necessary change to the crontab -e:

"/etc/init.d/crond stop" (Without quotes)

Once you use the command, I think your issue will be resolved.

If you using WHM for your server, then follow these steps to stop cronjobs:

1) Login to your control Panel.
2) Go to "Service Manager".
3) Uncheck "Cron Daemon" option.
4) Now, press on Save button.

If you still face any problem, report me so that I can assist you further.

Thanks,
Pratik Jajal

Comment: How I've to launch that command "/etc/init.d/crond stop"?. When I start my centos server I've to insert the login (my root user and password). But the resources to do the login are already burned from the cronjob. In cronjob there is a infinite loop without sleep

Comment: If you are unable to access the server, it's quite difficult to resolve your issue. If your necessary data is there in your VPS, I suggest you to consult your VPS provider to further troubleshoot otherwise you will need to re-install the OS.

Comment: One more thing, it you get the access of your server for a 5-10 second, you can copy paste the following command to fix your issue:

Comment: "service crond stop" (Without quote).

Comment: The server is in my home. But I'm sure there is a command to delete these rows in the crontab -e. I don't know maybe with grub. Or maybe entering in recovery mode

Comment: Yes, recovery mode will work for your issue. If you are unable to access the server, there is no hope to enter any command.

Comment: With recovery mode the cron jobs into the startup are executed?

Comment: I have not practically performed hence I am not sure for this but I think it will not run in startup the recovery mode. You can try.

Comment: I can't enter in recovery mode, if I select the item for the recovery it boots normal and can't login. I don't want to format everything

Comment: I can't enter in recovery mode, if I select the item for the recovery it boots normal and can't login. I don't want to format everything

Answer (score -2):

You can open crontab -e and can delete each job which runs at the scheduled timeframe. I don't think your problem might be related to crontabs.

Will it be possible if you can share us the snapshots of your issue so that we can try our best to fix it?

Thanks,
Pratik Jajal

Comment: I can't login anymore into the server: I've one command with the @reboot keyword and the problem is happened from this. I'm sure because the fan go very fast